# Length operator on array of objects inside object

Tags: html, angular, typescript, api, angular8

I have a response from API `res` it has type: `{"plan":[{"name":"ABC"},{"name":"DEF"}]}`. I am trying to store the `res` in my typescript as below:

```
this.apiCall.apiMethod(this.headers, this.data)
  .subscribe(
    async (res: any) => {
      if (res) {
         for (let i = 0; i < res.plan.length; i ++){
         if (i < 3) {
         this.ppp.push(res.plan[i]);
         this.plans = this.ppp;
```

In my HTML I am binding as follows:

```
<div class="columns" *ngFor="let p of plans; let i = index">
```

In my console I am getting the error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Can you tell me how can I run for loop and later bind to html an array of objects inside an object `res`?

Comment: Please try to do a `console.log(res)` in the callback and check if `plan` property is actually available.

Comment: I tried that already. It is exactly like this: ```{"plan":[{"name":"ABC"},{"name":"DEF"}]}```

Comment: Could you show us console.log(res)? Probably your res.plan doesn't exist

Comment: Does the code compile without any errors?

Comment: I did ```console.log(res)``` it returns: ```{"plan":[{"name":"ABC"},{"name":"DEF"}]}```

Comment: no errors while compilation. Only error I am getting is: ``` TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined```

Answer (score 0):

If the code compiles without any error, then it's most probably a TS Lint error. You could either define the type using class/interface or use bracket notation instead of dot notation to access the properties. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) for more on info on JS property accessors.

Try the following

```js
for (let i = 0; i < res['plan'].length; i ++) {
  ...
}
```

#### Update: Interface

Alternatively, you could define an interface to assert the type.

```js
export interface Name {
  name: string;
}

export interface Plan {
  plan: Name[];
}
```

And define the specific instead of `any`.

```js
this.apiCall.apiMethod(this.headers, this.data)
  .subscribe(
    async (res: Plan) => {       // <-- use `Plan` instead of `any` here
      if (res) {
         for (let i = 0; i < res['plan']length; i ++) {
           ...
```

You need to include all the possible properties in the object to the interface if you have more properties than what you've mentioned in the question.

Comment: I tried this way earlier. I was getting the same issue as mentioned. Am I doing the dot or bracket notation correctly? I have used bracket operator exactly as you mentioned and dot operator as I mentioned in the code

Comment: I am not exactly sure from the code you've shown. I've updated the answer to use an interface, please see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer if you don't have errors while compilation.

You can try to use bracket notation and ES6 spread.

```
    if (res) {
     res["plan"].map((plan, index) => {
       if(index < 3){
         this.ppp = [...this.ppp,res["plan"][index]];
         this.plans = [...this.ppp];
       }

     });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like below

```
this.apiCall.apiMethod(this.headers, this.data)
  .subscribe(
    async (res: any) => {
      if (res && res.plan && res.plan.length) {
         for (let i = 0; i < res.plan.length; i ++){
         if (i < 3) {
         this.ppp.push(res.plan[i]);
         this.plans = this.ppp;
```